# Definition of convergence of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, definition

Can this be a valid definition?

> For each $\epsilon>0$, there exists $K \in \Bbb N$ such that if $n\ge K$, then $|a_n-a|\le\epsilon$.

Should I use "$<\epsilon$" or "$\le \epsilon$"?

Comment: They are equivalent.

Comment: @SubhadeepDey: How can you say that that is more rigorous than something else if both statements are equivalent?

Comment: @SubhadeepDey: They are not almost equivalent, they are equivalent. I have no idea what almost equivalent is, or more rigorous, that makes no sense. You can prefer one of the definitions or even find one more natural than the other, but you cannot say one is more rigorous. Normally I wouldn't nag about language, but I was curious to know what you meant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following statements

1. For each $\epsilon>0$, there exists $K\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n\geq K \Rightarrow |a_n-a|\leq \epsilon$

and

2. For each $\epsilon>0$, there exists $K\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n\geq K \Rightarrow |a_n-a|< \epsilon$

are equivalent.

Proof of 1.$\Rightarrow$2.

For any $\epsilon>0$, we have $\epsilon/2>0$. Therefore by 1., there exists $K\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n\geq K \Rightarrow |a_n-a|\leq \epsilon/2<\epsilon$, which means 2. is true.

Proof of 2.$\Rightarrow$1.

Trivial because $|a_n-a|< \epsilon$ implies $|a_n-a|\leq \epsilon$